# error when generating index

Tags: errors, indexing, logging

The `.ilg` file is fulll of errors, and no `\index` command is accepted.

```
This is makeindex, version 2.15 [TeX Live 2011] (kpathsea + Thai support).
Scanning input file thesis.idx...
!! Input index error (file = thesis.idx, line = 1):
   -- Illegal page number \thepage.
...
   -- Illegal page number \thepage.
!! Input index error (file = thesis.idx, line = 28):
   -- Illegal page number \thepage.
done (0 entries accepted, 28 rejected).
Nothing written in thesis.ind.
Transcript written in thesis.ilg.
```

There is issued `\makeindex` before document, and the `\printindex` command is redefined (and issued at the end after `\bibliography`).

```
\let\my@prnt@nd@x\printindex
\renewcommandx\printindex{%
  \cleardoublepage%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\indexname}%
  \my@prnt@nd@x%
}
```

The `.idx` file has these lines (among others):

```
...
\indexentry{oscila\textcommabelow tie,~ecua\textcommabelow tie}{\thepage }
\indexentry{natural~numbers}{\thepage }
\indexentry{category,!balanced~definition}{\thepage }
...
```

For some reasons, in the class `.dtx`, i have redefined `\protected@write` which seems to be used by `\@wrindex`.

```
% \begin{macro}{\protected@write}
% \begin{macro}{\protected@write@immediate}
% \begin{macro}{\immediateaddtocontents}
% \begin{macro}{\addtocontentsline}
%    \begin{macrocode}
% redefine \protected@write to use \protected@write@immediate below
\long\def\protected@write#1#2#3{\protected@write@immediate#1{#3}[#2]}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Code borrowed from `multitoc.dtx' CTAN /macros/latex/contrib/ms %%
%%% Copyright [1998..1999]  Martin Schr\"oder. All rights reserved. %%
% \write with appropriate handling of |\protect| and |\thepage|; args:
% an output stream, some text to write, and some initialization code.
\newcommandx*\protected@write@immediate[3][3]{%
  \begingroup
    \let\thepage\relax
    #3%
    \let\protect\string
    \edef\reserved@a{\immediate\write#1{#2}}%
    \reserved@a
  \endgroup
  \if@nobreak\ifvmode\nobreak\fi\fi%
}
%%%                                                                 %%
%%%                                                                 %%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%    \end{macrocode}
% \end{macro}
% \end{macro}
% \end{macro}
% \end{macro}
```

There is only a blank page after the bibilography, and usually i had all index entries in the following page, but nothing is generated; appreciate any help or fix on this. Thank s.

Comment: It's a really *bad* idea to redefine `\protected@write` to begin with. Of course, if you declare `\let\thepage\relax`, `\thepage` becomes unexpandable and will be written literally in the file. It's quite unclear why you want to make all writes `\immediate`: it's a plainly wrong thing to do.

Comment: that's it, a simple backup/restore `\TeX`nique has resolved it.

Answer (score 7):

There should be *very good* reasons why you want to make all writes `\immediate`. It's usually a wrong thing to do, for many reasons. Here's one.

Suppose you want to produce a table of contents, which is a quite common thing in LaTeX documents. Suppose your depth of listing in the TOC is at least 1, so that sections are included. Suppose that a section title is found when TeX hasn't yet finished a page, but when it completes its tasks connected with this action, it realizes that the section title must be moved to the next page.

Here is the problem: the entry for the TOC in the auxiliary file will already have been written. And it will be *wrong*, off by one.

With a delayed write, the entry would be written only when the section title actually appears in a page. Therefore, doing all writes `\immediate` is plainly wrong; the same situation would appear for the index, as TeX might find an entry to index in a line that will eventually end up in the next page.

If you read the documentation of `multitoc`, you'll see that the code for `\immediateaddtocontents` (that uses `\protected@write@immediate`) was for adding something *without* the page number. That's why Martin Schröder does `\let\thepage\relax`: the token `\thepage` becomes unexpandable and will be written literally to an auxiliary file (and successively used macros will gobble it).

For index production it *must* be expandable, otherwise you'll get (as you indeed do) `\thepage` in the `.idx` file, which is pretty useless: you're losing the association between the entry and the page number. But it's not sufficient to remove that instruction: the write operation must *not* be immediate.

---

By the way, there is a much simpler way to make all write operations immediate:

```
\let\@@write\write
\def\write{\immediate\@@write}
```

(a double `\immediate` prefix is equivalent to one).